# jQuery tooltip plugin not making tooltips

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, tooltip

I'm having no luck getting the tooltips to work on Firefox.  So I decided to give the jQuery tooltip plugin a try.  But it's not working for me.

The images are being inserted into html by user action.  The status variable holds the string and the section of html below  (div class="statusicons"...) is what it looks like in firebug after the insert and tooltip() function is run.  The tooltip() doesn't modify the html in any way.  However, I'm not getting the "tooltip() is not a function" so I have to assume the code plugin is found.

```
<script src="/plugins/snap/jquery.tooltips.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
jQuery("#devinfo").jqGrid('setCell',id,'status',status);
$("#davo img[title]").tooltip();


<div class="statusicons" id="davo">
<img width="24" height="24" title="Drive not mounted" alt="Drive not mounted" src="/plugins/snap/images/mount2.png">
&nbsp;<img width="24" height="24" title="Drive not shared" alt="Drive not shared" src="/plugins/snap/images/share2.png">
&nbsp;<img width="24" height="24" title="Drive not busy" alt="Drive not busy" src="/plugins/snap/images/busy2.png">
&nbsp;<img width="24" height="24" title="Drive is spinning" alt="Drive is spinning" src="/plugins/snap/images/drive1.png">
&nbsp;<img width="24" height="24" title="Drive is precleared" alt="Drive is precleared" src="/plugins/snap/images/precleared1.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Amended Answer:**

Try this

Head section of your page as in `<head></head>` tags use a style sheet for your tooltip and set its display to none first.

Here is a small mockup based on what you have provided :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.tooltip {
    display:none;
    background:transparent url(/images/some_image.jpg);
    font-size:12px;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#fff; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script     
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="/jquery/jquery-latest.js" >
    </script>
    <script     
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="/jquery/jquery.tools.min.js" >
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#davo img[title]").tooltip();
});
    </script>   
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class="statusicons" id="davo">
    <img width="100" height="100" id="haha" title="Drive not mounted" src="/images/some_image_2.jpg">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And now:**

Since you are dynamically adding the images to the page in the code where you are adding the images to the page you will need to execute the following JQuery statement:

```
$(function(){$("#davo img[title]").tooltip();});
```

**This way every time it will get binded whther the images exist upon document.ready or you force it on every time you add things in.**

See this link also:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Comment: As per given requirement, "The images are being inserted into html by user action". But even if you add this on document load, it will not work when any new image is added dynamically.

Comment: We don't need to add $(function() { });
Just $('#davo img[title]').tooltip(); will do.
Also we need to use the newly created element instead of "id".
Thanks Pasha Immortals

Comment: @Vanga Sasidhar: Yes you do need it if you are dynamically adding. Because you need to force it.